# Prove that $I_k \otimes_k \Omega \rightarrow I$ is injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field, $k$ a subfield of $\Omega$, $I$ an ideal of $\Omega[X_1, ... , X_n]$, and $I_k  = I \cap k[X_1, ... , X_n]$.  Then $I_k$ is an ideal of $k[X_1, ... , X_n]$.  There is a well defined homomorphism of $\Omega$-modules: $$I_k \otimes_k \Omega \rightarrow I$$ given by $f(X) \otimes c \mapsto c f(X)$, which I believe should be injective.

Here is what I have so far as a proof.  Since $\Omega$ is a flat $k$-module, the inclusion $I_k \subseteq I$ gives that the natural map $$I_k \otimes_k \Omega \rightarrow I \otimes_k \Omega$$ is an injective homomorphism of $\Omega$ modules.  I would like to say then, that $I \otimes_k \Omega \cong I \otimes_{\Omega} \Omega$, or at least the former injects into the latter, since then $I \otimes_{\Omega} \Omega \cong I$.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following commutative diagram of $\Omega$-modules with exact rows.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> I_k \otimes_k \Omega @>>> k[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \otimes_k \Omega @>>> (k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I_k) \otimes_k \Omega @>>> 0 \\
\ @VVV @VV\sim V @VVV \ \\
0 @>>> I @>>> \Omega[x_1,\ldots,x_n] @>>> \Omega[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
$$